# Ubuntu cannot detect my HDMI port

Tags: nvidia, graphics, hdmi

I haven't been able to detect my laptop's HDMI port on Ubuntu for some time, while on Windows I have no problem, I reinstalled the open-source 460 driver nvidia cleanly after a totally purge from the previous driver, I have tried lots of solutions on the internet but none of them works, I have an nvidia gtx 1050 ti with an Intel Graphic 630 on Ubuntu 20.04, could someone help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which laptop do you have, but enable discrete graphic in BIOS settings works for me (Legion5 Ryzen 4800H + RTX2060). Unfortunately it drains battery a lot, ald can change brightness for now (kernel 5.10.10) Wish external monitor works on dedicated amdgpu card